# Ignore a property in moshi if the value is not present

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have the following property in my data class

```
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class CatalogProduct(
    @Json(name = "recommended")
    val recommended: Int = 0
) : Parcelable
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected an int but was BOOLEAN at path $.products[0].recommended at $.products[0].recommended
```

As the response I get back from the API may not contain that value as its optional.

The following will not show the error if the value is not present.

```
@Transient
@Json(name = "recommended")
val recommended: Int = 0
```

However, if the response contains that value then it will always be excluded

If I make the property nullable like this then the error will show again:

```
@Json(name = "recommended")
val recommended: Int? = 0
```

How can I have recommended so it will be ignored if there is no value present in the response and not ignored if there is a value?

I am using the following dependencies and version

```
moshiVersion = '1.11.0'

implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshiVersion"
implementation 'com.serjltt.moshi:moshi-lazy-adapters:2.2'
kapt "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:$moshiVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofitVersion"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ignore a property in moshi if the value is not present

In general, I just use `val propertyName: Type?`, it works fine in my project.

```
@Json(name = "email") val email: String,
@Json(name = "userName") val userName: String?,
@Json(name = "isSignup") val isSignup: Boolean?,
...
```

Regards your description, why not use `Boolean?`, because I checked the error :

> Expected an int but was BOOLEAN at path $.products[0].recommended at $.products[0].recommended

If I understand correctly, it means that the type doesn't match each other. The server return `Boolean` but you use `Int` in the data class.

How about this?

```
@Json(name = "recommended") val recommended: Boolean?
```